# Counting number of distinct integers in array

Tags: c++, algorithm

To find the number of distinct numbers in an array from the `l`th to the `r`th index, I wrote a code block like:

```
int a[1000000];
//statements to input n number of terms from user in a.. along with l and r

int count=r-l+1; //assuming all numbers to be distinct
for(; l<=r; l++){
    for(int i=l+1; i<=r; i++){
        if(a[l]==a[i]){
            count--;
            break;
        }
    }
}
cout<<count<<'\n';
```

**Explanation**
For an array say, a=`5 6 1 1 3 2 5 7 1 2` of ten elements. If we wish to check the number of distinct numbers between a[1] and a[8] that is the second and the 9th elements (including both), The logic I tried to implement would first take count=8 (no. of elements to be considered) and then it starts from a[1] that is 6 and checks for any other 6 after it, if it does find, it decreases the count by one and goes on for the next number in the row. So that if there are any more occurrence of 6 after that one, it would not be included twice.

**Problem** I tried small test cases and it works. But when I tried with bigger data, it did not work, so I wanted to know where would my logic fail?

*Bigger data, as in integrated with other parts of the program and then used. Which gave incorrect output*

Comment: what do you mean by "didn't" work?

Comment: @ig-melnyk By didn't work, I mean that there seems to be a problem in the logic, that I am not able to figure out. It does not give the desired output. I.e gives wrong no. of distinct numbers. I just want you to check the correctness of my algorithm. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes. if(a[l]==a[ind]) what's that? Was it supposed to be "i"?

Comment: @ig-melnyk Yes, it was. Sorry. Corrected now

Comment: Btw, this algorithm is quadratic, it might be more interesting to sort the table ( O(nlog(n)) ) then iterate through the table once.

Comment: if you really want help you should publish http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Slava I tried my best to reduce the problem as per my capabilities. Could you tell me which part was unclear and I will improve that?

Comment: @DakshShah do you understand what MCVE is? Is your example compilable?

Comment: @DakshShah could you please post an example where it fails?

Comment: @SimoV8 That is the problem, I don't know where my program falls.

Comment: @Slava I would just upload a compilable code link if that is desirable

Comment: @DakshShah "But when I tried with bigger data, it did not work" - that bigger data, that is where it fails. That is what we need.

Comment: Would you mind another solution that will work correctly?

Comment: @ig-melnyk Sure, but I am also curious to know why this one fails. If someone could tell that

Comment: @davmac I am sorry, but I don't have that "bigger data", it is part of a big problem which I was trying to solve. So it works good for all the test cases but not the long input that the server checks on its own and does not provide to the user

Comment: You don't count all the duplicates, you `break` after the first one.

Comment: @DakshShah how big your bigger data? What difference you have with expecetd result? Bigger, smaller? Significantly?

Comment: @Galik I do, as. When the number comes for the first time, it searches for one occurrence decreases the count and then continues the loop and moves forward in the array, so eventually that very number will come up and then it will look for the 3rd occurrence of the same integer and so on and so forth

Comment: @Slava That is the problem, I hardly know anything about the bigger data or it's output. I was trying have the logic error figured out directly. Sorry, can't help with that

Comment: @DakshShah what I only see that condition in first loop should be `for(; l<r; l++){` but that should not affect correctness. Looks like the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @DakshShah is `l` always larger then `r` in the testcases? Is it possible that `l` is smaller then 0, or `r` larger then the size of the array?

Comment: @DakshShah and what is `a`? Is it large enough to store a very big array of numbers (without generating a stack overflow)?

Comment: @Wimmel I don't know what creating stack overflow is. But it is some where of the size of 10^6 ints

Comment: @DakshShah what is the declaration of `a`? It is important because if you use `int *a;` and allocate it using `new` (or `malloc`), there should be no problem. But if you use `int a[size];` where size is 1000000, you will likely run into a stack overflow.

Comment: @Wimmel I am not using a pointer...

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use `std::set`

Basic idea is to add all the elements into your new set, and just output the size of your set.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int l = 1, r = 6;
    int arr[] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5};
    set<int> s(&arr[l], &arr[r + 1]);
    cout << s.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a warning that `std::set` can be rather slow because it does so many allocations. You may be better of with `std::sort` in some cases.

Comment: Also you should use `std::unordered_set`, not `std::set`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer that does not use `std::set`, although that solution is probably simpler.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int input[10]{5, 6, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 1, 2};    //because you like raw arrays, I guess?

    std::vector<int> result(std::cbegin(input), std::cend(input));    //result now contains all of input
    std::sort(std::begin(result), std::end(result));    //result now holds 1 1 1 2 2 3 5 5 6 7
    result.erase(std::unique(std::begin(result), std::end(result)), std::end(result));    //result now holds 1 2 3 5 6 7
    result.size();    //gives the count of distinct integers in the given array
}
```

Here it is [live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98934fa69842431a) if you're into that.

--

**EDIT:** Here, have a short version of the set solution, too.

```
#include <set>

int main()
{
    int input[10]{5, 6, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 1, 2};    //because you like raw arrays, I guess?

    std::set<int> result(std::cbegin(input), std::cend(input));
    result.size();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first question to ask with this type of problem is what is the possible range of the values. if the range of numbers `N` is "reasonably small", then you can use a boolean array of  size `N` to indicate whether the number corresponding to the index is present. You iterate from `l` to `r`, setting the flag, and if the flag was not already set increment a counter.

```
count = 0;
for(int i=l; i<=r; i++) {
   if (! isthere[arr[i]]) {
       count++;
       isthere[arr[i]] = TRUE;
   }
}
```

In terms of complexity, both this approach and the one based on set are O(n), but this one is faster as there is no hashing involved. For small `N`, for example for numbers between 0-255, most likely this is also likely to be less memory intensive. For larger `N`, for example if any 32-bit integers is allowed, the set based approach is more suitable.

Comment: `isthere` can be a `std::bitset<256>`.  I agree that for larger possible values, a `set` is the way to go.  A `std::bitset<65536>` would still fit in CPU L1 cache (65536/8 = 8kiB), so it's an ok choice if your input is very long.  Otherwise touching a bunch of scattered cache lines only once each will be really slow.

Comment: For long input sequences, always setting the bit / bool, and then counting the number of set entries afterwards, would be faster with one byte per entry.  With a bitmap, though, setting an arbitrary bit is more expensive.  (since you have to read-modify-write).  You'll prob. get a lot of branch mis-predicts once repeats start to occur, but with really long inputs, this gets amortized over cheaper per-input-value operation in the already-present case.

Comment: This is a really useful solution for small N. +1

Answer (score 1):

You said you didn't mind another solution. So here it is. It uses set - a structure that stores only unique elements. By the way, on the bigger data - it will much faster than solution with two cycles.

```
    set<int> a1;
    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
    {
        a1.insert(a[i]);
    }
    cout << a1.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the below process I'm giving process of counting unique numbers. In this technique you just get unique elements in an array. this process will update your array with garbage value. So in this process you can't use this array (that we will use) further anymore. This array will automatically resize with distinct elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // for using unique (library function)

int main(){

    int arr[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3};

    int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr); // finding size of arr (array)

    int unique_sz = std:: unique(arr, arr + len)-arr; // Counting unique elements in arr (Array).

    std:: cout << unique_sz << '\n'; // Printing number of unique elements in this array.

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to handle that problem (That I told before), you can follow this process. You can handle this by coping your array in another array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // for using copy & unique (library functions)
#include <string.h> // for using memcpy (library function)

int main(){

    int arr[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3};
    int brr[100]; // we will copy arr (Array) to brr (Array)

    int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr); // finding size of arr (array)

    std:: copy(arr, arr+len, brr); // which will work on C++ only (you have to use #include <algorithm>
    memcpy(brr, arr, len*(sizeof(int))); // which will work on C only

    int unique_sz = std:: unique(arr, arr+len)-arr; // Counting unique elements in arr (Array).

    std:: cout << unique_sz << '\n'; // Printing number of unique elements in this array.

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){ // Here is your old array, that we store to brr (Array) from arr (Array).
        std:: cout << brr[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd just use standard algorithms

```
#include<algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     int arr[] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5};
     int *end = arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);

     std::sort(arr, end);

     int *p = std::unique(arr, end);

     std::cout << (int)(p - arr) << '\n';
}
```

This obviously relies on being allowed to modify the array (any duplicates are moved to the end of `arr`).   But it is easy to create a copy of an array if needed and work on the copy.

Comment: To use completely standard, you may use `int end = std::end(arr);` and `std::distance(std::begin(arr), p)`.

Comment: There is nothing non-standard in the above - relative to any C++ standard - but I agree some may prefer to use `std::end()` [C++11] and `std::distance()` [any C++ standard].   `std::end()`  would return an `int *`, not an `int` though.

Comment: By standard I mean `std`, not compliant code. Misuse of `sizeof` happens silently, whereas `std::end()` fail at compile type with simple pointer. (true, typo for `int* end`)

Comment: This is unnecessarily slow. `std::unique` modifies the array and you don't need to. Just loop through it checking whether each element is the same as the previous one and increment a counter if not.

Comment: @Timmmm - The complexity of `std::unique()` is linear in number of elements, whereas `std::sort()` is greater than that i.e.  O(N log N).   So the sorting will dominate.    In any event, the question stated no requirement on performance.   If performance is identified as a concern (e.g. testing and profiling of a working program) it is not difficult to tweak as you suggest.  But, unless there is an identified performance concern all your approach offers is premature optimisation.

Comment: Yes but the `std::sort()` is unavoidable, and the `std::unique()` isn't. And sure if you don't care about speed `std::unique()` is fine, though the more efficient code isn't significantly more complex.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Use this:

```
template<typename InputIt>
std::size_t countUniqueElements(InputIt first, InputIt last) {
    using value_t = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type;
    return std::unordered_set<value_t>(first, last).size();
}
```

There are two approaches:

1. Insert everything into a set, count the set. Because you don't care about the order you can use a `std::unordered_set` which will be faster than `std::set`. `std::set` is implemented as a tree which does a lot of allocations so it can be slow.
2. Use `std::sort`. If you want to preserve the original array you'll need to make a copy of it.

Here is a complete example.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

template<typename RandomIt>
std::size_t countUniqueElementsSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last) {
    if (first == last)
        return 0;
    std::sort(first, last);
    std::size_t count = 1;
    auto val = *first;
    while (++first != last) {
        if (*first != val) {
            ++count;
        }
        val = *first;
    }
    return count;
}

template<typename InputIt>
std::size_t countUniqueElementsSet(InputIt first, InputIt last) {
    using value_t = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type;
    return std::unordered_set<value_t>(first, last).size();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 6};
    std::cout << countUniqueElementsSet(v.begin(), v.end()) << "\n";
    std::cout << countUniqueElementsSort(v.begin(), v.end()) << "\n";

    int v2[] = {1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 6};
    std::cout << countUniqueElementsSet(v2, v2 + 6) << "\n";
    std::cout << countUniqueElementsSort(v2, v2 + 6) << "\n";
}
```

Using that loop in the sort version should be faster than `std::unique`.

The complexity of 2. is worse than 1. - the average case is O(N) vs O(N log N). But it avoids allocation so may end up being faster for small arrays or ones that are already sorted or mostly already sorted.

You should definitely *not* use `std::set`, and probably not use `std::unique` (though it does lead to fewer lines of code, and won't make that much difference to performance so up to you).

In any case, in most cases you should go with the set version - it's a lot simpler simpler and should be faster in almost all cases.

3. As other people have mentioned, if you know your input domain is small you can use a `bool` array instead of an `unordered_set`.